# Xilinx XPS : On what bases the AXI master changes AWSIZE/ARSIZE....?

Tags: c, verilog, xilinx

I have built my system with AXI interface using AXI4 From XILINX PLATFORM STUDIO(XPS).

I used 32 bit data and address buses.I am facing problem with respect to xSIZE.

In firmware(SYSTEM C), I have 8 bit, 16 bit and 32 bit Read/Write operations.Based on the Read/Write width, The AXI xSIZE has to be changed. i.e For 8 bit(type- char), 16 bit(type- short) and 32 bit(type- int) Read/Write's, the AXI xSIZE has to be changed to 2'b00, 2'b01 and 2'b10 respectively.

My question is- Why AXI xSIZE is always set to 2'b10 by the AXI Master, Since we can't change/modify AXI Master...????

Please help us to solve this problem..

Answer (score 1):

The SIZE bits specify the axi bus width. To do a shorter write, use the STRB bits to specify which bytes are valid.

See the [axi spec](http://www.gstitt.ece.ufl.edu/courses/fall15/eel4720_5721/labs/refs/AXI4_specification.pdf), page A3-49

> Write strobes
>
> The WSTRB[n:0] signals when HIGH, specify the byte lanes of the data
>   bus that contain valid information. There  is one write strobe for
>   each eight bits of the write data bus, therefore WSTRB[n] corresponds
>   to  WDATA[(8n)+7: (8n)]. A master must ensure that the write strobes
>   are HIGH only for byte lanes that contain valid data. When WVALID is
>   LOW, the write strobes can take any value, although this specification
>   recommends that they are  either driven LOW or held at their previous
>   value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.. We made changes and Now our IP is working perfectly.